# JQuery: slideDown() wont overwrite hide() a 2nd time

Tags: jquery, css

I have a header and a menu. The goal is to click a 'Show' button in the header which will hide the header, with slideUp, and show the menu, with slideDown.

In the menu, there is a 'Hide' button that hides the menu and shows the header again (with slideUp and slideDown again).

There is also a `.hide-for-mobile` class that hides the menu element that must be removed and replaced each time.

See my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/uy9omboz/6/

```
$(".show").click(function() {
   $(".header").hide();
   $(".menu").hide().removeClass("hideme").slideDown(400);
});

$(".hide").click(function() {
  $(".header").slideDown(400);
  $(".menu").slideUp(400).delay(400).queue(function(next) {
      $(this).addClass("hideme");
  });
});
```

The menu shows and hides correctly the first time, but if I click show again it no longer shows. The inline style `display: none` provided by `.hide()` no longer seems to get removed by `.slideDown()`.

Would anyone know why this is and where I've gone wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like below  using `toggleClass()`:-

```
$(".menu").slideDown(400).delay(400).toggleClass("hide-for-mobile");
```

Working example:-

```js
$(function() {
  $(".show").click(function() {
    $(".header").hide();
    $(".menu").slideDown(400).delay(400).toggleClass("hide-for-mobile");
  });
  $(".hide").click(function() {
    $(".header").slideDown(400);
    $(".menu").slideDown(400).delay(400).toggleClass("hide-for-mobile");
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.menu {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 200px;
}

.hide-for-mobile {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <a class="show">Show</a>
</div>

<div class="menu hide-for-mobile">
  <a class="hide">Hide</a>
</div>
```

Comment: MeltingDog  glad to help you:):)

Answer (score 1):

u don't need queue method to make chaining with jquery methods.

```
 $(".menu").slideUp(400).delay(400).addClass("hide-for-mobile");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uy9omboz/7/

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this easily with** `addClass()` and `removeClass()` . No need to use complex method as this can be done with this.This works in two ways:

**1. click of `.show` menu class `slides down` and class `hide-for-mobile` is
    `removed`.**

**2. Now on click of `.hide` in the menu the class `.hide-for-mobile` is
    `added` and header is `shown up`.**

```
$(function() {

  $(".show").click(function() {
    $(".header").hide();
    $(".menu").slideDown(400).removeClass("hide-for-mobile");
  });

  $(".hide").click(function() {
    $(".header").slideDown(400);
    $(".menu").slideUp(400).addClass("hide-for-mobile");

  });

});
```

> Here is a working example that depicts the slideup slidedown show
>   hide:

```js
$(function() {

  $(".show").click(function() {
    $(".header").hide();
    $(".menu").slideDown(400).removeClass("hide-for-mobile");
  });

  $(".hide").click(function() {
    $(".header").slideDown(400);
    $(".menu").slideUp(400).addClass("hide-for-mobile");

  });

});
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.menu {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 200px;
}

.hide-for-mobile {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <a class="show">Show</a>
</div>

<div class="menu hide-for-mobile">
  <a class="hide">Hide</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use bellow snippet

```
$(function() {
 $(".show").click(function() {
    $(".header").hide();
    $(".menu").slideDown(400).toggleClass("hide-for-mobile");
 });
 $(".hide").click(function() {
    $(".header").slideDown(400);
    $(".menu").slideDown(400).toggleClass("hide-for-mobile");
 });
});
```

In your code you have use `.hide()` and then `slideDown()` which is not needed, and this issue is due to `queue(function(next)` this method. if you want to use your code then simply remove `queue(function(next)` method to make it work.